# #OCaml ocamldoc generation error

Tags: compilation, ocaml, ocamldoc

Hello I'm trying to generate ocaml documentation with ocamldoc. I'm trying the following command : ocamldoc -html alpha.mli -d doc/

But I have this error :

```
File "compiler/alpha.ml", line 16, characters 12-23:
Error: Unbound module Id
File "compiler/argHandler.ml", line 3, characters 17-27:
Error: Unbound module Parser
File "compiler/ARMGeneration.ml", line 7, characters 38-41:
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
File "compiler/ARMGeneration.ml", line 8, characters 47-59:
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
File "compiler/ARMGeneration.ml", line 11, characters 10-33:
Error: Unbound module Exception
File "compiler/ASMLGeneration.ml", line 7, characters 44-60:
Error: Unbound module Syntax
File "compiler/id.ml", line 44, characters 38-61:
Error: Unbound module Exception
File "compiler/knorm.ml", line 11, characters 4-14:
Error: Unbound module Syntax
File "compiler/letfold.ml", line 4, characters 4-15:
Error: Unbound module Syntax
File "compiler/main.ml", line 15, characters 4-24:
Error: Unbound module ArgHandler
File "compiler/regAllocation.ml", line 202, characters 18-29:
Error: Unbound module Id
File "compiler/SyntaxArm.ml", line 8, characters 12-16:
Error: Unbound module Id
File "compiler/syntax.ml", line 20, characters 12-16:
Error: Unbound module Id
11 error(s) encountered
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error will happen when `ocamldoc` can't locate the `.cmi` generated by the build.

In order for it to work you need to first compile your project and then point `ocamldoc` towards the `_build/compiler` folder where you `.cmi` are

A valid command for you might look like :

```
ocamldoc -html -I _build/compiler compiler/*.ml -d doc/
```

the `-I` option indicate that you will specify the folder where the `.cmi` are.